# List of GridView into a ScrollView - Why last item scrollable?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `LinearLayout` into a `ScrollView`.

Then, I have a loop, where I add several `GridView` with `TextView` into my `LinearLayout` (with `addView()`).

I don't understand why the last gridView is scrollable into my ScrollView.

And it shows just 2 items... (I have 4 items into my loop)

[image]

**GridView**

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="4"
    android:isScrollContainer="false"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />
```

**TextView**

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
```

**Fragment**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/darkGrey"
        android:orientation="vertical">


    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Use RecyclerView inside another RecyclerView. Checkout my sample for detail. https://github.com/sagartrehan/NestedRecyclerSample

Comment: So the image is confusing, because it shows a LinearLayout inside a ListView (instead of ScrollView)

Comment: Sorry, image has been changed

Comment: Problem fixed with this class https://github.com/DigitalCampus/oppia-mobile-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/digitalcampus/oppia/utils/ui/StaticGridView.java